# Error con función que devuelva posición y cadena de diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

Diseñar una función que, dada una lista de cadenas, devuelva el diccionario resultante de utilizar como clave la posición de la cadena en la lista la y, como valor, la cadena. Sólo hacerlo con cadenas que tengan mínimo una vocal.
Me devuelve el diccionario vacío.

```
def correct2(l):
    i = 1
    result = {}
    for c in l:
        if "aeiouAEIOU" in c:
            result[i] = c
        i += 1
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Por el enunciado parece una tarea académica, por tanto la forma de resolverlo depende de qué conozcas hasta el momento del lenguaje Python.

Si conoces los conjuntos, la solución es muy sencilla pues basta crear un conjunto con las vocales, y para cada palabra de la lista verificar si la intersección de ese conjunto con el conjunto de letras de la palabra no es vacío.

Así:

```
def correct2(lista):
    vocales = set("aeiouAEIOU")
    result = {}
    for indice, palabra in enumerate(lista):
        if vocales & set(palabra):
            result[indice] = palabra
    return result

lista = ["Esto", "es", "una", "prueba", "y", "http", "es", "un", "protocolo"]
correct2(lista)
```

---

```
{0: 'Esto', 1: 'es', 2: 'una', 3: 'prueba', 6: 'es', 7: 'un', 8: 'protocolo'}
```

Sin usar conjuntos tendrás que iterar por la lista de vocales y para cada elemento comprobar si aparece en la palabra. Si encuentras que sí, la guardas en `resultado[]` y dejas de buscar más vocales en esa, pasando a la siguiente palabra. No te doy el código en este caso para que lo intentes tú.

Answer (score 0):

El problema (ya comentado por abulafia) lo tienes en esta línea:

```
if "aeiouAEIOU" in c:
```

Lo que en realidad estás haciendo es, verificar si la cadena completa `"aeiouAEIOU"` se encuentra en alguna de las palabras de la lista. Cosa que seguramente no ocurre. De ahí el diccionario vacío.

La solución es verificar individualmente cada uno de los caracteres de cada elemento y ver si se encuentra en la cadena `"aeiouAEIOU"`. Una forma simple, es hacer un poco de "comprensión" de listas:

```
if any(char in "aeiouAEIOU" for char in c):
```

- Tomamos cada caracter de `c` y
- Vemos si existe dentro de la cadena `"aeiouAEIOU"`.
- El resultado serán varios `True` y/o `False`, con `any()` devolvemos `True` si al menos hay una coincidencia.

Eventualmente, es posible que sea más rápido si la búsqueda la hacemos contra un `set`con las vocales en vez de una cadena plana, algo así:

```
vocales = set('aeiouAEIOU')
if any(char in vocales for char in c):
```